# Select2 issue more than one result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I have a problem with Select2 where it will only allow one section in the `<input>`. I cannot use `<select>` with the multiple as it is a limitation of select2 apparently when using ajax for data results.

Sample code (json data is at the bottom) http://jsfiddle.net/YeEmP/

```
id: function(data){
    return {
        product_id: data.product_id
    };
}
```

I suspect the problem is with the above code but can't be sure. When searching for a model eg D7000 it appears correctly like the example shown here [image: image1]

However if I search for another model number i.e D7100 it will say no results found but the ajax request returns the model just as if it was D7000.

[image: image2]

If I search for the model it didn't recognise first it works, vice versa.

[image: image3]

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but my complete code can be found in the jsfiddle link, it might not work as my datasource is ajax in the example but I have passed the json array as a commented out section.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution. I am having the same issue.

Comment: I ended up copy pasting it from their example page and seemed to work, the only different thing between my code and their code was the ordering of the functions sub functions.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the bug anymore, something browser side must of been doing it I suppose.. no reply from the dev either :(